# Two digit Placeholder in Numeric Input field

Tags: html, css

I have the following `form`.

```html
<form>
  <span>
        <input type="number" name="amount_in_dollars" id="amount_in_dollars" value="0" min="0"  />
      </span>.
  <span>
         <input type="number" name="amount_in_cents" id="amount_in_cents" value="00" min="0" max="99" placeholder="00" />
        </span>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

In the `amount_in_cents` field I'd like to have the default value `00`.

Note: `placeholder` doesn't seem to be working in `number` fields, but there  is a way for me to accomplish what I want?

Comment: Works fine for me / on chrome Browser / Do you want me to post html ?

Answer (score 1):

just remove **value="00"** it will work

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to have `value` because you are using `placeholder`, you have to add `placeholder` in your first `input` although

```html
<form>
  <span>
    <input type="number" name="amount_in_dollars" id="amount_in_dollars"  min="0" placeholder="0"  />
  </span>
  <span>
     <input type="number" name="amount_in_cents" id="amount_in_cents"  min="0" max="99" placeholder="00" />
  </span>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```